# System accumulates busy after a PostgreSQL migration. Same Tomcat7 and system files as before

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, tomcat7, connection-pooling

I migrated a system to other machines with a new version of Postgres. (8.2.23 to 9.4.5) (We tested new version for a long time and solved some compatibility errors). The application has the same files (same server: tomcat7) and users are using the same tasks that they performed before.

I monitoring "Data Sources" in "psi-probe 3.0".

System rapidly tracing the limit of active connections. (many BUSY).
Now for example, i have 15 BUSY without any "idle in trasaction" processes showed in Server Status (pgadmin). Only "idle" processes. (indicating a normality). To avoid locking the system I put: maxActive = "200". (just delaying until reach the limit).

Trying to solve i upgraded JDBC driver: "postgresql-8.3-604.jdbc3" to "postgresql-42.2.2.jre7". (did not solve)

Here my config in context for connection pool control:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/emp1" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" maxWait="10000" maxActive="200" maxIdle="5" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="1200" logAbandoned="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" username="*" url="jdbc:postgresql://*:**/*" password="*"/>
```

After searching solution I added the parameters: (removeAbandoned, removeAbandonedTimeout and logAbandoned) imagining that the problem would be traced in the application log and maybe BUSY would be removed after "removeAbandonedTimeout". (It didn't happened).

I noticed some strange situations after migration:

- When I stop tomcat the processes of "PostgresSQL JDBC Driver" are not finalized as it was before.
- Sometimes an "idle in transaction" processes persists with a simple query: "SELECT nextval('sequence_seq01') as sequential".
- BUSY appears also without any process "idle in trasaction".

A long time ago I had a problem of accumulate BUSY but it was symmetrical with the processes showed in Server Status (pgadmin) with "idle in transaction". I fixed the code that was not closing the connection. (but it's not the case now)

Comment: FIXED! The problem was in firewall with a timeout.

Comment: I did not have access to the firewall but it would be nice if postgres generated some exception to track the error